# Resize and group content grid

Tags: jquery, css

> **How to make the effect of grouping and deployment div's with different
>   content on the full page with jquery?**.

For example, i have 4 div's with content with width 20%  for each. http://jsfiddle.net/v2pwww/Hyccq/

[image]

I want that when onclick on each block, he turned around to the full page, and the rest were grouped.

*clicked div2*

[image]

**Please help!**

Comment: I know how to resize same block to full page on onclick action, but dont know how to grouping div's like an image.

Answer (score 2):

This does the job: 
http://jsfiddle.net/carlosmartinezt/Hyccq/1/

Comment: lol so easy:)
upd: if i have hidden block how to calculate margin-top and consider changing the page size http://jsfiddle.net/v2pwww/Hyccq/7/

Comment: Use jquery to obtain the height